# Oracle DBFS on AIX

Tags: oracle, filesystems, aix

I am looking at planning to store WebSphere transaction logs in a Oracle database using Oracle DBFS.

Oracle DBFS needs FUSE to work in Linux and Solaris.

I am unable to get clarity on whether Oracle DBFS needs FUSE on the other platforms. My platform is AIX.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17605/adlob_client.htm#ADLOB46006 does not provide clarity on whether it is required in an AIX environment.

**I am not sure if this is a valid query in the stackOverflow forum or does it belong to another forum such as Server Fault?**

Appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: This is definitely not a programming question.

Comment: Depends how you want to use it. "The dbfs_client can be used as a direct RDBMS client [...] on Linux, Linux.X64, Solaris, Solaris64, AIX, HPUX and Windows platforms. The dbfs_client can only be used as a mount client on Linux, Linux.X64, and Solaris 11 platforms. " [SecureFiles Dev's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17605)

Comment: APC,Thanks. http://isu.ifmo.ru/docs/doc112/appdev.112/e10645/adlob_client.htm seems to suggest that mount client is available only on Linux (not even Solaris). The link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17605/ that you specified in your response returns a 404.

Comment: How do i move this to an appropriate forum - Would Server Fault be the right forum for this question?